# Python like memoization in C#?

Tags: c#, python, memoization

Is there a similar way in C# to do the following:

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not args in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.f(*args)
        return self.memo[args]

@Memoize
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Comment: if you could explain what you are doing in this code it would be easy for Non python users to answer your question

Comment: @Kyle I am caching results of function calls using a decorator in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it manually with a `Dictionnary<int, int>`:

```
public static int Fibonacci(int x)
{
    var t = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    Func<int, int> fibCached = null;
    fibCached = n =>
    {
        if (t.ContainsKey(n)) return t[n];
        if (n <= 2) return 1;
        var result = fibCached(n – 2) + fibCached(n – 1);
        t.Add(n, result);
        return result;
    };
    return fibCached(x);
}
```

Comment: what does the  '=>' do?

Comment: [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)